# what does this symbol from KV265 mean?

Tags: notation

At 5:41, in the 17th bar of the 6th variation, there is a star above the C in the righthand.

what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

It's an asterisk, which usually indicates a comment at the bottom of the page (in this case Vgl. Krit. Bericht: compare critical comment).[image]

Comment: A more idiomatic translation might be "see editorial notes" or "see editor's note."